# Error: Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals

Tags: matlab, matrix, size

I have one 194-by-1 matrix. When I try to find its size, I get this message:

> `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

All values are positive and logical, what is the problem?

Comment: Can you post the part of code that triggers this error?

Comment: Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054047/subscript-indices-must-either-be-real-positive-integers-or-logicals-generic-sol) for [the generic solution to this problem](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20054048/983722).

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that you accidentally override the `size` function?

```
>> which size
```

Should give this output

> built-in (C:\ X X X \toolbox\matlab\elmat\size)

If you get something like

> size is a variable

Then you override the function.

To ammend this you'll have to `clear` the variable

```
>> clear size
```

Now you can use the function

```
>> size( A )
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you provide your code? It should work if you do it like this:

```
[rows cols] = size(A);
```

or

```
rows = length(A);
```

Answer (score 2):

In MATLAB, [`size`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) is a function that returns the dimensions of an array (a matrix, a cell array, etc...). However, MATLAB also supports [*overloading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading). When you call `size(A)` (assuming `A` is your matrix), the MATLAB interpreter first checks if there are overloaded variables/functions with the name `size`.

Apparently you have a variable named `size`, judging by the error message, so for MATLAB `size(A)` means that your trying to index into the matrix `size` with the subscript variable `A`. It seems that `A` has one or more zero elements, and since non-positive indices in MATLAB are forbidden, this triggers the aforementioned error.

The simplest solution is to use another name for your variable `size` so you can call the built-in function `size` without any issues.